# Get access token from habr API

Tags: http, oauth-2.0

I can't get token from https://test-career.habr.com/
I have login and verified application. I receive a code and I need to exchange it for a token, but I can't do it. I get a 401 error.
Habr uses OAUTH2.

```
 {String content =  "client_id=client_id";
        content += "&client_secret=client_secret";
        content += "&redirect_uri=redirect";
        content += "&grant_type=authorization_code";
        content += "&code=" + code;

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, content);
         Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://test-career.habr.com/integrations/oauth/token?"+content)
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", getAuth(client_id, client_secret))
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

                .build();


         Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(response.code()));
}

  public String getAuth(String client_id, String client_secret) {
        String auth = client_id + ":" + client_secret;
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
        return authHeader;
    }
```

client_id, client_secret, redirect is my id, secret and uri from habr.